# Use SQLite save score for a game

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to make a class, `HighScore`, to save scores for a game. I use `SQLite` and `ListView` display. Here's my code:

class HighScoreData:

```
public class HighscoreData {

public static final String SID = "scoreId";
public static final String SLEVEL = "level";
public static final String SSCORE = "score";

public static final String DB_NAME = "ScoreDB";
public static final String DB_TABLE = "Score";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;
private DBHelper mDBHelper;


public HighscoreData(Context c)
{
    this.mContext = c;
}

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Score(scoreId integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, level int, score int);");
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i("DBAdapter", "Updating database...");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Student");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
/**
 * 
 */
public HighscoreData openDB()
{
    mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mContext, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
/**
 * close
 */
public void closeDB()
{
    mDBHelper.close();
}
/**
 * insert record
 */
public long insert(int level, int score)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SLEVEL, level);
    cv.put(SSCORE, score);
    return mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
}
/**
 * 
 */
public boolean edit(int _id, int level, int score)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SLEVEL, level);
    cv.put(SSCORE, score);
    return mDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, SID + "=" + _id, null) > 0;
}
/**
 * 
 */
public boolean remove(int _id)
{
    return mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, SID + "=" + _id, null) > 0;
}
/**
 * 
 */
public void removeAll()
{
    mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, null, null);
}
/**
 * 
 */
public Cursor getAllScores()
{
    return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{SID, SLEVEL, SSCORE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
/**
 * 
 */
public Cursor getScoreById(int _id)
{
    Cursor mCursor = mDB.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[]{SID, SLEVEL, SSCORE}, SID + "=" + _id, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(mCursor != null)
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}
}
```

class HighScore :

```
public class Highscore extends Activity {

private Cursor mCursor;
private ListView listView;
String level;
String score;
String str = new String();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscore);
    mCursor = BeginGame.hsData.getAllScores();
    final ArrayList<String> arrayWork = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, arrayWork);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.hScore);
    if(mCursor.moveToFirst()) { 
        do{
        level =String.valueOf(mCursor.getInt(1));
        score =String.valueOf( mCursor.getInt(2));
        sb.append("Level :").append(level).append(" - ");
        sb.append("Score :").append(score).append("\n");
        }while(mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    str = sb.toString();
    arrayWork.add(str);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
}   
}
```

When I save a score in SQLite, I can open the `HighScore` activity, but when I opened SDK time first, it threw an error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the error, but the first thing I see is that you do not have your primary key columns name set to "_id".

This is required for Android to use this data in almost any widget.  It is how it keeps track of the data.  Not only do you need it in the DB, you must call for it so it is in any cursor you use to back up an adapter.  You don't need to display it, but it must be there.